# crystal Reports issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have below code for passing parametrs to open crsytal report. But when it opens crystal report i was asking parameters again to show the report.

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;
        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("DMTR1.rpt"));
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = m_strConnectionString.Split(';')[0].Split('=')[1]; 
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = m_strConnectionString.Split(';')[1].Split('=')[1]; 
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = m_strConnectionString.Split(';')[2].Split('=')[1]; 
        crConnectionInfo.Password = m_strConnectionString.Split(';')[3].Split('=')[1]; 
        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@ReceivedDate", Convert.ToDateTime("06/21/2013"));
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@TransferDate", Convert.ToDateTime("08/21/2013"));
        crysview.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crysview.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Did you check with _crysview.DataBind();_ instead of _crysview.RefreshReport();_ ?

Comment: Thank u so much. crysview.DataBind(); is working fine instead of crysview.RefreshReport();

Comment: So now it does not ask for parameters ?

Comment: Thanks Coder. i will add this as answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `crysview.RefreshReport();` with `crysview.DataBind();`.